# Why does newer glibc implement posix_spawn with vfork instead of fork?

Tags: linux-kernel, fork, race-condition, glibc, vfork

I am tracing posix_spawn source code in glibc 2.17 and glibc 2.27.

(glibc 2.17: sysdeps/posix/spawni.c)

(glibc 2.27: sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/spawni.c)

I found glibc 2.17 uses vfork or fork depending on flags and file actions.

I guess it is due to multithread safety or race condition.

But in glibc 2.27, it only uses vfork to create a subprocess.

Why does glibc change the implementation?

Is the newer linux kernel better to protect vfork against race conditions?

Comment: You may find your answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433702/vfork-calls-sys-vfork-but-fork-calls-sys-clone

Comment: This is good but I want to clearly understand why glibc 2.17 use fork if there are file actions and why glibc 2.27 doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vfork` is substantially more efficient for large processes than `fork` because the address space does not have to be duplicated at all.  Originally, there were concerns that proper cancellation handling would require the use of `fork` in case of file actions present, but eventually, it was determined that the current `vfork`-based implementation was adequate.

`vfork` is still broken in qemu-user and Microsoft's emulation, but the bugs usually are not visible when using `posix_spawn` because it does not actually use `vfork`, but a `vfork`-style `clone` system call with a separate stack, so that even if the parent process is not properly paused, the stack in the child is not clobbered.

Some resources with background information:

- [posix_spawn should use vfork() in more cases than presently](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10354)
- [posix: execvpe cleanup](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-01/msg00622.html) (plus subsequent review threads)
- [posix: New Linux posix_spawn{p} implementation](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-01/msg00623.html) (likewise)
- [glibc "linux: spawni.c: simplify error reporting to parent"](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2017-11/msg04729.html) (discussion of the assert which exposes the `vfork` emulation bug)
- [Windows emulation vfork bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2615) (likewise)